# Using CSV files as input to run exchange management shell commands

Tags: powershell, csv, exchange-server, exchange-management-shell

I have a csv that looks like this:

[csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qF3so.png)

Column A is the account alias, B is the OU, c is firstname, D is lastname and so on. I want to run the `New-Mailbox -Alias firstlast -Name FirstLast -OrganizationalUnit domain/OU -FirstName firstname -LastName lastname - DisplayName "First Last" -UserPrincipalName firstlast@domain.com`

How do I get the CSV file to function as the input for these cmdlets? I'm familiar with the `Import-CSV` cmdlet but I'm unsure of how to get it to work in these specific circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

```
Import-Csv file.csv | % { New-Mailbox -Alias $_.Alias -Name $_.Name ... }
```